# How to manage files on an MTP Portable Device?

Tags: c#, android, mtp

I have been researching this topic for days and I can't find anything on managing files on a MTP Portable Device (More specifically a Galaxy S4).

I want to be able to...

- Copy files from the PC to the MTP Device
- Copy files from the MTP Device to the PC
- Delete files from the MTP Device

I really want to copy MP3 files but if there is a general way to copy over and file supported by MTP that would be awesome. I've looked into the Window Portable Device API but I couldn't find anywhere where there is sample code in C#.

Any blogs, sample code, and files would be very helpful. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi Chrish did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: No I haven't, i was looking into the Windows SDK but I don't understand how to implement it into my project.

Answer (score 13):

I used a nugetpackage called [MediaDevices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaDevices/)

this made it very easy for me to copy my photos from my android phone to my computer.

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var devices = MediaDevice.GetDevices();
        using (var device = devices.First(d => d.FriendlyName == "Galaxy Note8"))
        {
            device.Connect();
            var photoDir = device.GetDirectoryInfo(@"\Phone\DCIM\Camera");

            var files = photoDir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                device.DownloadFile(file.FullName, memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                WriteSreamToDisk($@"D:\PHOTOS\{file.Name}", memoryStream);
            }
            device.Disconnect();
        }

    }

    static void WriteSreamToDisk(string filePath, MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
            memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesnnt work..
Error CS0117 'MediaDevice' does not contain a definition for 'GetDevices'

Comment: This nuget package works great for me, glad I found this article. One issue I had with very large video files was using MemoryStream, i.e. allocating byte[] bytes would fail, etc. But then I found that another instance of DownloadFile(string source, string destination) writes directly to file - exactly what I needed. The package comes with a nice CHM manual conveniently installed in the project hierarchy.

Comment: Either import MediaDevices, or use MediaDevices.MediaDevice.GetDevices(); to work around the namespace issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a nuget package called WPDApi which worked well for me, after I managed to download the source code (had problems with nuget):

https://github.com/Duke-fleed/WPDApi