# Access phone files via .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, usb, mount-point

I have a OnePlus attached to a Windows machine via USB.

I can see the file system objects on it via File Explorer.

[image: Phone drives in File Explorer]

The phone is exposed via two locations, the `D:` drive, which is mounted as a CDFS and contains some OnePlus drivers.

The other, labeled `ONEPLUS A6013` which contains the OS file system.

How do I access the volume labeled `ONEPLUS A6013` from .NET?

There's no drive for it returned by the `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` and I can't reference it by the path in File Explorer?

```
This PC\ONEPLUS A6013\Internal shared storage\Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60478271/4412472

A [MediaDevices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaDevices/) nuget package is required.

The code may look like this:

```
static void EnumerateOnePlusFiles()
{
    var deviceName = "ONEPLUS A5010";

    var devices = MediaDevice.GetDevices();
    var device = devices.First(d => d.FriendlyName == deviceName);

    device.Connect();

    var photoDir = device.GetDirectoryInfo(@"\Internal shared storage\DCIM\Camera");
    var files = photoDir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
    }

    device.Disconnect();
    device.Dispose();
}
```