# How to access a Windows 10 Device in C#

Tags: c#, ios, windows-10, mobile-devices

When you plug in (via USB) a mobile phone into a Windows 10 laptop, it comes up as a device. How do I access the files on this in C#. For example an iPhone when plugged in shows like this:

[image: Windows 10 devices with iPhone plugged in]

I would like to get all of the data off of that. I have already tried using the paths 'This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage' and '\This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage', both crashed the programming saying that they could not find the files.

I am then going to read and copy files off this in C#

Note: I would like this to work for all types of phone, not just an iPhone (Android and iPhone would be fine though).

Comment: You're looking for the MTP protocol. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512737/how-to-manage-files-on-an-mtp-portable-device#60478271) helps

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Sorry for the late response, I was customising it to make sure it would work for my case as this is not a simple a copy-and-paste test. Thanks again :). Feel free to put it as an answer, I will upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem you're trying to resolve is to access a device through the MTP protocol. The question has been asked before on SO.

You can try to use [Windows Portable Device API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/portable-devices-com-api/) directly (I'm assuming this is windows due to the screenshot).

Another option would be using the [MediaDevices NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaDevices/) like the linked answer does.

Comment: @Community the first link is documentation of the API